# Boost.Log linking error on OS X El Capitan v10.11.3 and Xcode 7.2 Beta (LLVM 7.0.2, clang -700.1.81)

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, boost

I'm new to stack overflow and have a question about Boost.log. I'm very interested on using Boost.log library but I have failed terribly trying to make it work. My setup is described on the "Title". The Boost libraries were succesfully installed throught homebrew, so the "include" and "Cellar" folders can be found on the system and each path to mentioned folder are "included" on Xcode. I'm trying to compile a very basic example:

```
namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace src = boost::log::sources;
namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;
namespace keywords = boost::log::keywords;

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    logging::add_file_log( keywords::file_name = "sample_%N.log", keywords::rotation_size = 10 * 1024 * 1024, keywords::time_based_rotation = sinks::file::rotation_at_time_point(0, 0, 0), keywords::format = "[%TimeStamp%]: %Message%" );

    logging::core::get()->set_filter( logging::trivial::severity >= logging::trivial::debug );

    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL( trace ) << "A trace severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL( debug ) << "A debug severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL( info ) << "An informational severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL( warning ) << "A warning severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL( error ) << "An error severity message";
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL( fatal ) << "A fatal severity message";*/

    return 0;
}
```

When compiling no errors came up but when the app runs next error pops-up:

**dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN5boost3log11v2_mt_posix15parse_formatterIcEENS1_15basic_formatterIT_EEPKS4_S7_
  Referenced from: /Users/MMIN/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDL_OSX64_TLOM-hfqbehwlyjmogdapcmgoqggriedk/Build/Products/Debug/SDL_OSX64_TLOM
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libboost_log_setup.dylib
 in /Users/MMIN/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDL_OSX64_TLOM-hfqbehwlyjmogdapcmgoqggriedk/Build/Products/Debug/SDL_OSX64_TLOM
Program ended with exit code: 9**

I have reading some blogs and forums and it seems the problem is the gcc version used by homebrew and clang version used by xcode.

Could anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: I finally solved a similar problem (El Capitan, vanilla Homebrew install, Boost::Log, trivial log example). I don't use the Xcode IDE, but I was having trouble with linker errors on the command line until I used this: 

`c++ -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK   -lboost_log-mt  -o main main.cpp`. 

(No space between '-' and 'D')

Might be worth trying...